# Open the gmapInfoWindow of a specific marker from the Managed Bean

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with Primefaces whose version is 5.2. I used gmap and gmapInfoWindow. I need that from the Managed Bean open the gmapInfoWindow of a specific marker.

Here is the Code

infoWindow.xhtml

```
<h:form>  
    <p:gmap id="gmap" center="36.890257,30.707417" zoom="13" type="HYBRID" model="#{infoWindowView.advancedModel}" style="width:100%;height:400px">

        <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{infoWindowView.onMarkerSelect}" />

        <p:gmapInfoWindow id="infoWindow">
            <p:outputPanel style="text-align: center; display: block; margin: auto">

                    <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/antalya/#{infoWindowView.marker.data}" height="150" />
                    <br />
                    <h:outputText value="#{infoWindowView.marker.title}" />

            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:gmapInfoWindow>
    </p:gmap>

    <!-- Preload for demo -->
    <p:outputPanel style="display:none">
        <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/antalya/konyaalti.png" />
        <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/antalya/ataturkparki.png" />
        <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/antalya/kaleici.png" />
        <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/antalya/karaalioglu.png" />
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

and My ManagedBean InfoWindowView.java

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.data.gmap;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.event.map.OverlaySelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.map.DefaultMapModel;
import org.primefaces.model.map.LatLng;
import org.primefaces.model.map.MapModel;
import org.primefaces.model.map.Marker;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class InfoWindowView implements Serializable {

    private MapModel advancedModel;

    private Marker marker;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        advancedModel = new DefaultMapModel();

        //Shared coordinates
        LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(36.879466, 30.667648);
        LatLng coord2 = new LatLng(36.883707, 30.689216);
        LatLng coord3 = new LatLng(36.879703, 30.706707);
        LatLng coord4 = new LatLng(36.885233, 30.702323);

        //Icons and Data
        advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "Konyaalti", "konyaalti.png", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png"));
        advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord2, "Ataturk Parki", "ataturkparki.png"));
        advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord4, "Kaleici", "kaleici.png", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/pink-dot.png"));
        advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord3, "Karaalioglu Parki", "karaalioglu.png", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png"));
    }

    public MapModel getAdvancedModel() {
        return advancedModel;
    }

    public void onMarkerSelect(OverlaySelectEvent event) {
        marker = (Marker) event.getOverlay();
    }

    public Marker getMarker() {
        return marker;
    }
}
```

Comment: You copy-pasted http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/infoWindow.xhtml ... That's not working for you?

Comment: The example of PrimeFaces http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/infoWindow.xhtml works for me correctly, then the gmapInfoWindow runs when I click on a marker in specific, but what I need is that from the Managed Bean run the gmapInfoWindow of a specific marker. Thanks